# Selecting an element inside a jquery element selector

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div

```
   <div id="dialog-confirm-error-validating-choices" title="Pop up">
        <p><span class="floatLeft"></span>
        <p id="error-message"></p></p>
    </div>
```

that I select with jQuery and I put it into a variable

```
var messageDialog = $('#dialog-confirm-error-validating-choices');
```

I want to set the inner html of an element within this variable

```
messageDialog.filter('#error - message').innerhtml("Hello");
```

Is this how it is done? Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $messageDialog = $('#dialog-confirm-error-validating-choices');
$messageDialog.find('#error-message').html("Hello");
// alternative: $('#error-message', $messageDialog).html("Hello");
```

Note that `innerHtml` is the method to change the HTML of a plain javascript element, whereas for a jQuery object you need to use the `html()` method. Also, the convention is to prefix variables which contain jQuery objects with a `$`.

Comment: Thanks Rory. This worked a treat. Thanks for noting about the jquery convention too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#error-message').html("Hello")
```

Note that the function `html` sets the html

Also note that I updated your query, to match the id of the element

Answer (score 0):

Considering the element you're looking to select has a unique ID, the most efficient selector would be its ID:

```
  $('#error-message').html('hello');
```